# Azure Web Service - Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: javascript, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I've just published my web application on Azure Cloud. I have a problem with one of views - when I try to get this view, I receive an error:

[image]

Console logs:

[image]

Other views works properly.
There is no error when I run app locally.

Answer (score 0):

- I have deployed the  `Asp.Net core-web-Api`  with  `.Net 6.0`  using visual studio 2022.
- it worked fine in my local environment as below.

[image]

- Deploying the Web application to azure use the below steps.
- Right click on the  **project**  and select  **publish**  as below.

[image]

- After clicking on publish below are the steps that you have to follow.

[image]

- We need to select Wich operating system we need to use as below.

[image]

- Click on create

[image]

- We need to fill the details like  `Name`,  `Subscription name`,  `Resource Group`,`Host plan`  and click on  **Create**

[image]

- After the above step web application is ready to deploy to azure portal click on  **finish**.

[image]

- The click on deploy.

[image]

- After successful deployment it will automatically open the azure portal web app link.

[image]

- I have follow the steps that you have provided but i am able to deploy it without any problem.

[image]